# Problem with #include "CppUnitTest.h" in VS2019 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am trying to add unit tests to an existing project. 
I added the following elements in the project options:
Include Directories: **"$(VCInstallDir)Auxiliary\VS\UnitTest\include"**
Libary Directories: **"$(VCInstallDir)Auxiliary\VS\UnitTest\lib"**
After all, he doesn't see the test header in cpp files.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the ProjectSubType property to your .vcxproj file, the include directory where the CppUnitTest.h is located will be added to the include path, for example

```
 <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    ...
    <ProjectSubType>NativeUnitTestProject</ProjectSubType>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Note: The actual directory where the file CppUnitTest.h is located has changed between different versions of Visual Studio.